# What is ~なかって and how is it formed?

Tags: meaning, conjugations

Taken from [alc.co.jp](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/UTF-8/):

> 家{いえ}の鍵{かぎ}が見{み}つからなくて、玄関{げんかん}のベルを鳴{な}らしたけど、君{きみ}、家{いえ}に居{い}**なかって**し、ここでずっと待{ま}ってたんだよ。
>
> (I rang the doorbell because I couldn't find the house key, but you weren't home, so I was waiting for you all this time.)

I've been trying to form the bolded portion but I can't find a way to derive it.

These are the forms that I know, and none of them match the bolded portion above:

> ~ない
>
> ~なく
>
> ~ないで
>
> ~なくて
>
> ~なかった

I'm guessing that it comes from なく + あって(て-form of ある) + sound contraction.　But I have no idea what it means and how it should be used.

**(Question)** What does ~なかって mean and how should it be used? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typo of `居なかったし` 'were not there, and'.